# Battle.net Api Authentication

Tags: c#, api, authentication, curl, oauth

I try to get an access token and I following this guide:

Here is my code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token"))
    {
        var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{client_id}:{client_secret}"));
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

        request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=>httpClient.SendAsync(request)).Result;

        test = response.RequestMessage.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
    }

    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/token/?namespace=dynamic-eu"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer "+ test);

        var response = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => httpClient.SendAsync(request)).Result;
    }
}
```

The first part to get an Authorization parameter works. But if I try the request I got an "401 Unauthorized" error.

Comment: Following what guide?  You didn't include a link in your question.

Comment: Sry https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/getting-started this guide

Comment: "_The first part to get an Authoriyation Parameter works._" Since you don't provide any evidence for your claim, i guess i have to take your word for it... ;-)

Comment: client _id and client_secret are only numbers and chars. No special chars or something like this. In addition i got a 200 OK response from this request. So it should be fine. There is also an Authentication string inside.

Comment: you are not passing the credentials...

Comment: Yeah, but the the string `"{client_id}:{client_secret}"` is just the string `"{client_id}:{client_secret}"`. Literally, that string. A string with curly braces, letters, underscores, a colon, and no numbers. But you said getting authorization parameters is working, so i suppose it is working, because you surely have verified that you pass a valid authentication parameter to the server, no?

Comment: If i change e.g. a number in the client_secret or client_id or if I remove the : than i got an 401 response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Sorry for taking your time. I forget to read out the content and there is the access_token.
Just added this line:

test = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;

After the first request and now it works. Thanks all for your help.